proof by mathematical induction problem
Ok so I'm trying to solve this mathematical induction problem and so far I got to a point but I can’t go any further the original problem is
Prove that for any positive integer n $$\sum_{j=1}^n j^3 = (\frac {n(n+1)} {2})^2$$
I done the problem up until i have
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} j^3 = \sum_{j=1}^k j^3 + (k+1)^3 = (\frac {k(k+1)} {2})^2 + (k+1)^3$$
somehow i need to turn
$(\frac {k(k+1)} {2})^2 + (k+1)^3$
into
$(\frac {(k+1)(k+2)} {2})^2$
but I'm stuck on how to proceed

Surely this is a duplicate.

This question is similar to: Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. Note there are also other duplicates, e.g., ...

(cont.) Prove summation using induction. In addition, there are also quite a few closely related questions, e.g., Proof by "infinite induction", Proving “The sum of $n$ consecutive cubes is equal to the square of the sum of the first $n$ numbers.”, etc.

@GerryMyerson FYI, this question is definitely a duplicate, as my comments above indicate.

@John, thanks for doing what I was too lazy to do.

We have $(\frac{k(k+1)}{2})^2+(k+1)^3=(\frac{k(k+1)}{2})^2+\frac{4(k+1)^3}{4}=\frac{k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3}{4}=(k+1)^2 \cdot \frac{k^2+4(k+1)}{4}=(\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2})^2$
So you only need to work on your expression  a little bit and you are done. That's very common and summation identies proved by induction often need algebraic manipulations at the end.

You are just there, the only thing you need to do is develop $(k+1)^3$ add it to the other term and simplify:
$$
\frac{(k)^2(k+1)^2}{4}+(k+1)^3 = \frac{(k^4+2k^3+k^2) + 4(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)}{4}
$$
Here things get a little messy, but if you add up all coefficients correctly you end up with:
$$
\frac{k^4+6k^3+13k^2+12k+4}{4}
$$
Now we develop the expression $(k+1)^2(k+2)^2 = (k^2+2k+1)(k^2+4k+2) = (k^4 +6k^3+13k^2+12k+4)$. From here, it is trivial to show that:
$$
\frac{k^4+6k^3+13k^2+12k+4}{4} = \frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}
$$
Just as we wanted.

So you got $[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}]^2 +[k+1]^3$
Taking $(k+1)^2$ common  we get
\begin{align}
&= (k+1)^2[\frac{k^2}{4} + (k+1)]\\
&= (k+1)^2[\frac{k^2+4k+4}{4}]\\
&= (k+1)^2[\frac{((k+1)+1)^2}{4}]\\
&= [\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}]^2\\
\end{align}
